# Junit not creating shared preference instance saying context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, sharedpreferences

I am writing a JUnit test cases for sharedpreferences as below

```
class SharedPrefTest {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = mock()
        userRepo = UserRepo(context)
    }

    @Test
    fun `check mocked instances are not null`() {
        context assertNotEquals null //mocked successfully
        userRepo assertNotEquals null
    } //PASS

    @Test
    fun `when shared pref instance not null then do further ops`() {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        sharedPreferences assertNotEquals null
    } //FAIL

    companion object {
        const val USER_PREFS = "userprefs"
    }

}
```

However, I am getting below error.

```
context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) must not be null
```

I have already checked context is not null in a separate unit test case but still its failing.

Comment: I don't understand the problem! You've already mocked the context. Why would it return a non-stubbed (non-null) response to getSharedPreferences?

Comment: Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for writing unit tests. You won't need to manually mock Android framework dependencies like Context.

Comment: @ashu Problem is while its not creating an instance of sharedpreference and throwing null error. Also, restricted to use Mockito

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is while its not creating an instance of sharedpreference and throwing null error.

Why would a mocked object invoke its concrete implementation? A mock object is a *stub* with its behaviour pre-configured for particular test scenarios. During tests, clients are expected to explicitly specify what happens if a particular method is invoked on a mocked object. If clients don't provide such a specification, a mocked object will often default to returning zero values for methods that don't return void; `null` in Mockito's (more specifically Java's) case.

You're mocking the `context`, hence, `context.getSharedPreferences()` returns the default `null` value. Since `sharedPreferences` field is declared as a Kotlin non-nullable type, assigning `null` to it throws the NPE. You can fix it by returning a mocked `SharedPreferences` instance from `context.getSharedPreferences()`.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `when shared pref instance not null then do further ops`() {
    val mockPrefs: SharedPreferences = mock()
    `when`(context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
        .thenReturn(mockPrefs);
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPreferences assertNotEquals null
}
```

A better approach would be to use a unit testing framework for Android, like [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

```kotlin
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SharedPrefTest {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
        userRepo = UserRepo(context)
    }

    @Test
    fun `check mocked instances are not null`() {
        context assertNotEquals null
        userRepo assertNotEquals null
    }

    @Test
    fun `when shared pref instance not null then do further ops`() {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        sharedPreferences assertNotEquals null
    }

    companion object {
        const val USER_PREFS = "userprefs"
    }

}
```

Reference: http://robolectric.org/androidx_test/